# Which db should I use for a small project?

Tags: mysql, microsoft-access

I`ve created a small project about a dentist. It is built with ASP and for my db I`m using MS Access. I think that he will add more or less about 1000-1500 records per year.

My fear is that there will be a day in which Access will not be able to handle all those records. Am I silly about this? Do you think that I should go for MySQL, or do you have any other recommendations? There is no matter of security because it is not going to work online.

Comment: SQL Express go all Microsoft.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. Do you think that this db will be faster than Access while it`s getting bigger with the records?